# Facebook permissions approval Watchkit app problems with ios_sim

Tags: facebook, ios-simulator, watchkit, ios-app-extension, apple-watch

We're trying to get `user_posts` approval from `Facebook` for a new `Apple Watch` app.  We've created an ios simulator build per FB instructions however they use **ios-sim** to test and its failing to run the app.  I know the app works in the iOS Simulator outside of `Xcode` because I've successfully loaded & tested it with `XCRUN` commands (loading the .app, .appex and watch kit.app objects and then running the .app or running the watchkit.app).

My thoughts on the issue are

- Possibly ios-sim hasn't installed the .appex and isn't designed to test .app's with app extensions.
- Possibly the user is not using the latest Xcode 6.2 and there's a problem with running Watchkit extensions

Details of the FB response below.  Has anyone else successfully tested an .appex with **ios-sim** or successfully submitted an .appex to Facebook for testing (specifically a Watchkit .appex) or has any advice on how to proceed? Would be much appreciated.

Searching Stackoverflow hasn't shown any related questions on this topic.  We've provided a feedback response to FB and posted on the FB developer forum as well.  Many thanks!

> Notes from our review team iPhone I received this error in my terminal
>   when trying to load the app:
>
> Last login: Tue Apr 7 13:12:02 on ttys003 chandlerhol-mbp:~
>   chandlerholmes$ ios-sim launch ~/Downloads/Swhorl.app/ Session could
>   not be started: Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0  "Unable to
>   run app in Simulator" UserInfo=0x7f9cb2a005e0 
>   {Error=AppexBundleUnknownExtensionPointIdentifier,
>   ErrorDescription=Appex bundle at 
>   /Users/chandlerholmes/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DF420CB7-66DA-405A-9FF8-A7AA84CE5806/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.kV56mj/extracted/Swhorl.app/PlugIns/Swhorl
>   WatchKit Extension.appex  with id com.verteq.Swhorl.watchkitextension
>   specifies a value (com.apple.watchkit) for the
>   NSExtensionPointIdentifier key in the NSExtension dictionary in its
>   Info.plist that does not correspond to a known extension point.,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=An error was encountered while running
>   (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0),
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9cb2802f20 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (LaunchServicesError error 0.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to run
>   app in Simulator}
>       chandlerhol-mbp:~ chandlerholmes$
>       iPhone
>       Your provided file has been configured incorrectly. For iOS Simulator Builds, follow our instructions and resubmit. For Android
>   submissions, please build a .APK file for upload.

Answer (score 0):

have now got an answer to this question.  We are now successfully approved for the **user_posts** permission! :) Here's how we achieved it, hope you will find this useful.

We re-submitted the application, no changes to screen shots or the build or instructions, but with the following paragraph prominent in the **Facebook login integration** section on the front page of the application:

> PLEASE NOTE BEFORE TESTING:  This app cannot be tested successfully
>   with IOS-SIM because its an Apple Watch app and it is not possible to
>   open an external display (Hardware/External Displays/Apple Watch) when
>   launched from ios-sim.  We've tested the simulator build successfully
>   using XCRUN, apple's own command line tools - please see user_posts
>   testing notes for detailed instructions and we hope this will be
>   satisfactory for you to your complete testing.  Many thanks

Here are the instructions that we included within the specific request for the user_posts permission:

```
PLEASE NOTE IOS-SIM WILL NOT WORK WITH THIS APP.  Its not currently possible to test 
an Apple Watch app with ios-sim, you cannot open the external display from 
the simulator. 

To test user_posts with Swhorl:

INSTALLATION

1. Open Xcode on a Mac with OS X Mavericks or Yosemite
    a. Select Xcode menu, About Xcode Ensure you have Xcode Version 6.2 (6C131e) or later
    b. Select Xcode menu, Open Developer Tool submenu, select iPhone Simulator
2. In iPhone simulator
    a. IOS Simulator menu, select Reset Contents And Settings 
    b. Select Hardware menu, Device submenu, then iPhone6
    c. Select Hardware menu, External Displays, Apple Watch 42mm
3. Locate the copy of the Swhorl simulator build uploaded with this submission place it 
   in a folder of your choice and double click to expand the zip file, then
    a. Open Terminal and change directory to the expanded 'Release-iphonesimulator' folder
    b. With the simulator running, install the 3 app components with these commands
        xcrun simctl install booted Swhorl.app
        xcrun simctl install booted Swhorl\ Watchkit\ App.app
        xcrun simctl install booted Swhorl\ Watchkit\ Extension.appex 
    c. Use the following commands to run the App and Watckit app respectively in the simulator
        xcrun simctl launch booted com.verteq.Swhorl
        xcrun simctl launch booted com.verteq.Swhorl.watchkitapp
```

As a separate recommendation, when digging through the Facebook help pages we noted that its possible to get **Direct Support** from FB, but only once you've registered as a business and connected your app.  An existing request that's failed won't automatically qualify for support, you have to re-submit.  However it DOES keep all the details of your previous submission, so no major re-typing needed.

You can read how to do that here [Facebook App Review Guideleine](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review) - scroll to the bottom of the page for the section on Direct Support.  We didn't need it this time but I recommend it as it may provide a channel for you to discuss your submission that you would not otherwise have.

Happy submitting!

Comment: Quick edit of the post as it lost all formatting for the installation instructions I pasted in... which its lost again :(  Finally fixed!